# core dumped when free pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, coredump

The structure of my code is like:

```
bool adj = true;
float ***a1=NULL, ***a2=NULL;

if (adj) {
    /* allocate memory for ***a1 */
    /* code body */
} else {
    /* allocate memory for ***a2 */
    /* code body */
}

/* free ***a1 */
/* free ***a2 */
```

When I compile the code, everything runs smoothly except at the end the screen pops up `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. The reason I doubt may come from `if...else...`: I only allocate memory for ***a1 when `adj=true` and leave `***a2=NULL`; but I free both of them at last two lines. So to avoid this error, maybe I should write:

```
if (adj) { /* free ***a1 */ } else { /* free ***a2 */ }
```

Am I right?

P.S. The size of each 3D pointer (`nt*nx*nz*sizeof(float)`) is less than `10^8`. (Assume the 3D pointer `a1, a2` can be written as `a1[it][ix][iz]` with `it, ix, iz` ranging from `0~nt-1, 0~nx-1, 0~nz-1`)

Comment: Use a debugger to walk through the program.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please.

Comment: A crash during free() indicates you have some pointer-related bug elsewhere in the program on that very same variable.

Comment: Can you prove that you do not free the same pointer twice or free one which has not been used to allocate memory?

Comment: It's perfectly OK to call `free(NULL)`.  That part of your original program is fine.  But you can't successfully use the allocated memory as a 3D array because the compiler has no idea how big each dimension is.  You must treat the allocated memory as a 1D array and compute the index explicitly from your `it`, `ix`, `iz` variables.

Comment: Show us your malloc() calls.